# Principal specialisation on the forgotten symmetric polynomial looks exceptional, why?

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

for any symmetric polynomial $u(\lambda,n)$ the principal specialisation is usually defined as $ps(u(x_1,x_2,x_3, ..)) = u(1,q,q^2,q^3, ..)$. See also [https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/standardSymmetricFunctions.htm](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Epeal/polynomials/standardSymmetricFunctions.htm).
I was surprised to find (conjecture) that the forgotten symmetic polynomials are exceptional in that $[n]_q! (1-q)^n \sum_{\lambda \vdash n} ps( f(\lambda) ) = q^{n(n-1)/2}$
All other symmetric functions produce less simple expressions. Why does the forgotten s.f. stand out in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

I can add a few related observations (conjectures):
$$
\sum_\lambda ps(m_\lambda) = \frac{1}{[n]_q!(1-q)^n}
$$

A partition is even, if all parts are even.

For even $n$,
$$
\sum_{\lambda: even } ps(f_\lambda) = 
\frac{ q^{(n/2)(n/2-1)} }{[2]_q [4]_q \dotsm [n]_q (q-1)^{n/2}} 
$$
and the sum is $0$ otherwise.

For even $n$,
$$
\sum_{\lambda: even } ps(m_\lambda) = 
\frac{1}{[2]_q [4]_q \dotsm [n]_q (1-q)^{n/2}} \text{ if $n$ even}
$$
and the sum is $0$ otherwise.